# Accepted Answer image is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

The bottom of the three hex image is being cut off by about 5 pixels or so. This is happening on the scifi.stackexchange.com/questions site and the meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions site. (Basically the pages where the list has the vertical votes and answer count as opposed to the horizontal counts.)

Comment: Side note: it's only happening on the /questions page, the basic site index page doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @thedaian thats what I meant by pages with vertical counts as opposed to horizontal counts.

Answer (score 3):

The fix will be in the next production build.